# add more values in the same form using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am working on Reservation System

I have a Form that Enters Information about a Voucher

The Voucher can have one Group 
and that one group can have many passengers

Now what i want to do is that Take all the information about a Voucher in the same form and add everything related to that voucher in database once Everything is entered by the user.

how am i planning to do it:
I have placed an Anchor tag that says "Add more Passengers" and onclick() function will be called that will reset those fields and then ajax will go to an php page and save those values somewhere temporarily that temporary place/variable should be Global or super Global cause i have to access them all when i have to finally add everything to the database at once 
but the problem is where do i store those values that were previously entered by the user

I really hope i have made my question clear, any help would be great and really thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to find the actual question in this.

Answer (score 1):

Store the data in the Session. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: but how do i add the different information of same type to a single Session
i mean that once user entered the information of a particular passenger the he clicks Add more this previous information is entered and saved in Session['Passenger_name']  then next time if he adds another passenger then it will got to the same page and then overwrite previous values in Session['Passenger_name'] if there is some array global array session type of thing then please tell

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend saving the data incrementally into the DB each step of the way.  This way your session remains light.  The session is really meant for data that must be stored there for easy access on all pages.

The only downside to this is that if the user gets 3/4 of the way through the forms/pages, and quits, you have a row with incomplete information.  I'd argue that this is a good thing to keep, and then you can prompt them to "finish what they started" later when they log back in!

So you see, there is no need to temporarily save anything.  Just REALLY save it in the DB, exactly where it should go.  On your next pages, your form can UPDATE MySQL instead of INSERTing.

Comment: Yes Sir i totally agree and for the downside you mentioned i am not adding the everything to DB incrementally

Comment: Yes, but you SHOULD add it incrementally =).  It means the data is saved immediately, and the user can come back and finish later.  It is the better solution in my opinion.